# Ignoring HTML entity for ampersand in MySQL Full-Text Search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, html-entities

I have a lot of data that is being entered into records with the HTML entity `&amp;`. A full-text search for the word "amp" will result in records containing `&amp;` to be shown, which is highly undesirable.

Presumably this is because MySQL ignores the '&' and the ';'. So does anyone know of any way within MySQL to force it to treat special characters as part of the word so that my search for "amp" doesn't include all results with `&amp;` in them - ideally **without** some form of subquery or extra WHERE clause?

My solution so far (not yet implemented) is to decode the entities on INSERT and re-encode them when displaying on the web. This would be ok, but adds some overhead to everything that I'd like to avoid if possible. Also it works well for new entries, but I would need to backdate it to nearly 7 million records... which I kinda don't want to *have* to do if I can help it.

--

I updated my `my.cnf` file with the following:

```
ft_stopword_file = /etc/mysql/custom-stopwords
```

Does there need to be any special permissions on this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "decode HTML entities on INSERT and encode them on output" is your best bet, that'll take care of things like `&quot;` as well. You'd probably want to strip out HTML tags too along the way to keep MySQL from finding things in attribute values.

If speed and formatting is an issue then you could stuff the text/plain version in a separate column and put your full text index on that and let everything else use the text/html version. Of course, you'd have to maintain both columns at the same time and your storage requirement would go up; OTOH, this approach would let you add tags, author names, and other extra bits of interesting data to the index without messing up your displayed text.

In the mean time, did you rebuild your full text index after you added the `ft_stopword_file` to your config file? AFAIK, the stopwords are applied on the way into the index rather than while the index is consulted.

Comment: After much consideration and deliberation, I feel that decoding the entities and storing them in a separate column is my best bet. It is the most flexible, if not the quite the cheapest option in terms of memory... an allowable side-effect methinks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to specifically ignore these. try to include `-&amp;` to your fulltext query. Another option and I am unsure if it requires a MySql source code change is to add amp and `&amp;` to the stop words list of MySql

Comment: Thanks Ashley. It would interesting to see if there's a performance difference between adding `-&amp;` to my MATCH-AGAINST declaration and `&amp;` to the stopwords list. I will give it a go!

Comment: I added it to the stopwords file, but it has had no impact unfortunately. And I can't add it to my query because I don't want it to affect results that contain that too `amp` and `&amp;`...

Answer (score 0):

You added it to the stopwords file and it's not working?  Sounds like either a bug in MySQL or your stopwords list isn't being used.  Have you reviewed [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)?  Quote:

> False hits or misses may occur for
>   stopword lookups if the stopword file
>   or columns used for full-text indexing
>   or searches have a character set or
>   collation different from
>   character_set_server or
>   collation_server.
>
> Case sensitivity of stopword lookups
>   depends on the server collation. For
>   example, lookups are case insensitive
>   if the collation is latin1_swedish_ci,
>   whereas lookups are case sensitive if
>   the collation is latin1_general_cs or
>   latin1_bin.

Could any of those possibility be impacting your stopword entry of &amp; not being read?

Comment: And here's also this description of the my.cnf config value that points to the stopword file.  It would be good to review that to ensure you haven't missed anything in setting up your stopword list.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I followed most of this to the letter after the Ashley's suggestion and I haven't been successful. I've updated my question